# script to find /rsync - a specific files between 2 dirs with identical internal folder structure

Tags: bash, rsync

I have two dirs which contain all the files for a mobile phone `system/rom`.  I'll call them `/rom1 and /rom2`
Both rom1 &  rom2 have identical directory structure within.

The full file path to each is similar to

```
User/me/development/rom1/system 
User/me/development /rom2/system
```

I want to copy `/ rsync -av` all the folders and files with  *camera*. * from rom1/system/  to its equivalent folder in rom2/system/

ie: generate a scrip that does...  `rsync  - av User/me/development/rom1/system/app/camera.apk  User/me/development/rom2/system/app/`

In case it's useful I have already generated a list of all the folders and files  including their  file path (starting at /system)  I want copied over.  It looks like :

```
system/app/camera.apk system/bin/lib/camera.so system/vendor/camera/ system/very-long-list /etc etc...
```

I know how to use Individual Unix tools but I'm having trouble putting it all together to do what I  want in a bash script.

this is a non functional example that will give you an idea of what Im trying to do.

```
DIR1=User/me/development/rom1/
OLDPATH=$(find . -name '*camera*.*' -exec $pwd { } \;) | NEWPATH=$(sed -s /rom1/rom2/ $OLDPATH) | for SELF in { } ; do 
  rsync --dry-run -Rav $DIR1$SELF $NEWPATH
```

Comment: Look at the `--include` option of `rsync` -- you don't really need `find` here.  Not properly a programming question; voting to close as off-topic.  Maybe you'll want to flag for moderator attention and request migration e.g. to [unix.se] but check their posting guidelines first, and make sure this isn't a duplicate of an existing question there.

Comment: Thanks. I agree I don’t need find. I just want to copy about 150 libs from roughly 25 separate locations from one dir tree to their corresponding place in  a different dir tree with identical internal folder structure. As I will be performing this action many times I don’t want to do it manually or type a line of code for each lib, app etc that gets copied. I need a script that will loop through each file,  save it including fie path as a variable, allow me to alter the path and save files to their new location.

Comment: Roughly then `rsync --include '*camera*' -avz ./rom1/./ ./rom2/./`